# Get index of random true value PER COLUMN in numpy 2-d array without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I would like to obtain the index of a random true value per column in a numpy 2-d array using the most efficient means possible (i.e. without a python for loop).

For example, given the following 2-d `numpy.ndarray`:

```py
np.array(
    [[True, False, False],
     [True, True, True],
     [False, True, False]]
)
```

Provide a 1-d `numpy.ndarray` that gives the random row index positions of true values per column (i.e. first axis):

```py
numpy.ndarray([0, 2, 1])
```

By counter-example, the following would NOT be correct:

```py
numpy.ndarray([2, 2, 1])
```

because, the 1st column has a non-True value in the third row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[True, False, False],
     [True, True, True],
     [False, True, False]]
)

result = np.argmax(a * np.random.randint(1, 100, size=a.shape), axis=0)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1 2 1]
```

The idea is that [np.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) will always choose a position where the array is `True`, then which one to choose randomly is done by the `random.randint` function. To each `True` value it will assign a random integer and you choose the index of the maximum.

Comment: Nice idea! I think it has to be over the second axis though

Comment: Thanks @yatu, the second axis isn't `axis=1` ?

Comment: Sorry, the first, axis=0

Comment: You should have 3 values I think

Comment: Dude, I don't know where you got this idea, I've never seen anything like this but I am more than impressed. Well done. Thank you for your answer.